# Regular expression with groups reverse lookup in a long string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, zendesk

I am trying to integrate and automate some tasks from ZenDesk. So far I managed to get an entire ticket json to a single line. The ticket may have responses, so it may have more than one tag field. Now I want to look for "tags": ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word_4"] in reverse and get a list("word1", "word2", "word3", "word_4"]. Unfortunately I am stuck with the regular expressions and using groups. The tags contain letters, numbers, - and _; vary greatly in number. After that I would use them to sort different tickets.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) might be a good place to start.

Comment: [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) is also a good place to look. If you could post some sample tickets we could help out better

Comment: If you have json, why not use the json package?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "look for tags in reverse"

However, if you want to retrieve a list of all the tags from the JSON you could do it in two steps:

Grab the tags: `"tags": \[(.*)\]`

Then match elements globally: `"(.*?)"`

However, if you have access to the JSON and a JSON parser why not use that?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can complete the same task by just not getting everything in a string, but by working with the dict that ZenDesk returns as a response. I should remember that if I NEED regex I am probably doing something wrong.